# automerge modification in the same file

Tags: git, github

I have new repository called myrepo and I have master branch with two previous commits, the first commit with a file1.txt and second commit with a file2.txt.

- After the second commit, created a new branch called file2Split.
- After that I realize that file2.txt is too big, how I want to split
  its content by creating a new file2a.txt, and then commit the
  modifications.
- myquestion is how can I automerge modifications in the same files.

Comment: "automerge" is unclear. Can you describe in other words what you want to achieve?

Comment: please edit your post instead of adding information in comments. Use comments to say that your post is edited :)